# Do not bring a line of tables

Tags: mysql, sql, categories

Alright, let's to business ...

say I have a category (categoyid) '150 ', and would not bring anything that is in that category .....

It turns out that an article may be in multiple categories, and the more I block 150 in the category SELECT, it will still come to be linked to other categories ....

How do I, so that any item in the category '150 'is not sought in the SELECT even though he was also in another category than the '150' ...

Tables:

## `node`

```
nodeid
contentid
url
publishdate
```

## `nodeinfo`

```
nodeid
title
```

## `node_category`

```
categoryid
nodeid
```

## `article`

```
contentid
previewimage
```

=====================
I tried :

```
SELECT p.nodeid, p.contentid p.publishdate, p.url, c.categoryid, c.nodeid, a.previewimage, a.contentid, e.title FROM `node` AS p 
INNER JOIN `nodecategory` AS c ON p.`nodeid` = c.`nodeid` 
INNER JOIN `article` AS a ON p.`contentid` = a.`contentid` 
INNER JOIN `nodeinfo` AS e ON p.`nodeid` = e.`nodeid` 
WHERE c.`categoryid` 
IN (73,74,77,105,71,70,72,76,100,80,79,78,81,108,145,146,82,142,83,97,153) 
GROUP BY c.nodeid 
ORDER BY p.`publishdate` 
DESC LIMIT 4
```

Comment: It's nice that you posted the table names and columns.. But it would be even better if you could post some data.

Comment: The table name node_category in the post doesn't match what's referenced in your SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need a not-exists clause:

```
 AND NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT 1
  FROM 
   `nodecategory` AS ic
  WHERE
   p.`nodeid` = ic.`nodeid`
   AND ic.`categoryid` IN (150)
 )
```

Here it is in your query, reformatted a bit:

```
SELECT 
 p.nodeid, 
 p.contentid,
 p.publishdate, 
 p.url, 
 c.categoryid, 
 c.nodeid, 
 a.previewimage, 
 a.contentid, 
 e.title 
FROM 
 `node` AS p 
 INNER JOIN `nodecategory` AS c ON p.`nodeid` = c.`nodeid` 
 INNER JOIN `article` AS a ON p.`contentid` = a.`contentid` 
 INNER JOIN `nodeinfo` AS e ON p.`nodeid` = e.`nodeid` 
WHERE c.`categoryid` 
 IN (73,74,77,105,71,70,72,76,100,80,79,78,81,108,145,146,82,142,83,97,153) 
 AND NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT 1
  FROM 
   `nodecategory` AS ic
  WHERE
   p.`nodeid` = ic.`nodeid`
   AND ic.`categoryid` IN (150)
 )
GROUP BY c.nodeid 
ORDER BY p.`publishdate` 
DESC LIMIT 4
```

This should filter out nodes that are in one of the chosen categories, but are not also in those specified in the not-exists clause.